# cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.AddTask = function () {
    $scope.tasks.push([{
        "taskName": $scope.taskName,
        "priorty": $scope.selectedP
    }]);
};
$scope.tasks = [{
    "taskId": 1,
    "taskName": "task 1",
    "priorty": 1
}, {
    "taskId": 2,
    "taskName": "task 2",
    "priorty": 2
}, {
    "taskId": 3,
    "taskName": "task 3",
    "priorty": 3
}];
```

I got an error of cannot read property 'push' of undefined in angularjs

app demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/ObKoQn2tZ4evgJpKQBpH?p=preview

Comment: `$scope.tasks` is undefined. Do `$scope.tasks = []` before you call `push`.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Angular but I'm guessing you have to somewhat initialize the `tasks` array before adding elements to it

Comment: Where is this `cannot read property 'push' of undefined` occurring? I don't see it in your plunkr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your plnkr looks fine. although you should use

```
$scope.tasks.push({
    "taskName" : $scope.taskName,
    "priorty": $scope.selectedP
});
```

instead of an additional `[]`.

Comment: Spot on, Good eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

See this function:

```
$scope.AddTask = function() {
  $scope.tasks.push([{
    "taskName": $scope.taskName,
    "priorty": $scope.selectedP
  }]);
};
```

You must remove `[]` before `{}` in `$scope.tasks.push`, they're pushing another **array** inside `$scope.tasks` and they must push an **object**.